# Link UIScrollView and UIPageControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Hey I have a view contains multiple UIScrollView produced programmatically which means it's impossible to use the global variable to link these 2. So I am trying to use key-value coding scheme. Below is the code snippet.

```
    UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 240, 320, 30)];
    pageControl.numberOfPages = [holder_items count];
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageTurn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell addSubview:pageControl];

    [picScrollView setValue:pageControl forKey:@"pagecontrol"];
    [pageControl setValue:picScrollView forKey:@"scrollview"];
```

But the xcode complains:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pagecontrol.'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a custom class for that inherit that class from `UISCrollView` and create your veriable inside that class to hold that. And replace UIScrollView with that custom class.